# Problems with the MAX() IN SQL: not returning all desired information

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I am exploring a dataset in Microsoft SQL Server Management, regarding sales.
I want to obtain the day with the highest number of items sold for each year, therefore a table like this (the values in the rows are totally random):

| Year | Purchase Day | Max_Daily_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 2011-11-12 | 48 |
| 2012 | 2012-12-22 | 123 |

I first tried to run this query:

```
WITH CTE_DailySales AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Purchase_Day, 
        Year, 
        SUM(Order_Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Purchase_Day, Year) AS Daily_Quantity_Sold
    FROM 
        [sql_cleaning].[dbo].[Sales$]
)
SELECT   
    Year, MAX(Daily_Quantity_Sold) AS Max_Daily_Sales
FROM 
    CTE_DailySales
GROUP BY  
    Year
ORDER BY  
    Year
```

It partially works since it gives me the highest quantity of items sold in a day for each year. However, I would also like to specify what day of the year it was.

If I try to write `Purchase_Day` in the Select statement, it returns the max for each day, not the single day with the highest number of items sold.

How could I resolve this problem?

I hope I've been clear enough and thanks you all for your help

Comment: Is `Year` not always equal to `DATEPART(Year from Purchase_Day)` ?    I think there is no reason for grouping on year.

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Comment: @Luuk Yes, you are right. I only feel more confident keeping both Year and Purchase_Day for this query

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get you max value, your query would be:

```
WITH CTE_DailySales AS
( 
    SELECT Purchase_Day, 
        Year, 
        SUM(Order_Quantity) Daily_Quantity_Sold,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY SUM(Order_Quantity) DESC) as rn
    FROM 
        [sql_cleaning].[dbo].[Sales$]
    GROUP BY Purchase_Day, 
        Year
)
SELECT   
    *
FROM 
    CTE_DailySales
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it doesn't give me what I would like, since it returns all days for each year. Instead, I would like to have, for each year, the one day that had the biggest number of items sold.

Comment: @Gabriele.F i updated the query, you're right, in the partition by i should take only the Year

Comment: It worked perfectly this time, it returns what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
SELECT Purchase_Day, 
       Year, 
       SUM(Order_Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY Purchase_Day, Year) AS Daily_Quantity_Sold,
       MAX(SUM(Order_Quantity)) OVER(PARTITION BY Purchase_Day, Year) AS MAX_QTY_YEAR
FROM   [sql_cleaning].[dbo].[Sales$];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, It doesn't work since it gives me the following error: <Column 'sql_cleaning.dbo.Sales$.Purchase_Day' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.>  If I try  < GROUP BY Year, Purchase_Day and Order_Quantity>, it returns all days in the table, the sum of the items sold and the biggest transaction of the day (e.g.: I sold 8 items total in day x, and the biggest transaction was 3 items).

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Try the last version I wrote